# how to switch all column that are integers into numeric except 2 columns in read.table

Tags: read.table

I do not understand why my data, when I *read.table* it becomes in he form of integer instead of numeric. I need the first and last column, named taxonomy and row.names to remain in the for of "character". I thought I may specify that each column is numeric except the two mentioned above but I can not get my way around...

`x <- read.table (file = dfList[8],
                  sep = "\t", 
                  header = TRUE, 
                  dec = ".", 
                  quote = "", 
                  #as.is = TRUE, 
                  #fileEncoding="UCS-2LE",
                  #stringsAsFactors = TRUE,
                  #na.strings = 0,
                  colClasses=c("taxonomy"="character", "row.names"="character", "^(?!taxonomy$|row.names)"="numeric"))`

thanks

Comment: It would be helpful if you can show us what `x` looks like, e.g. by pasting the output from `dput(head(x))` or `str(x)`.

Comment: Actually it turns out that integer or numeric worked. Thanks anyway